# Add enchantment to custom item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.weapon.offhand minecraft:skull 1 3 {display:{Name:"Rasengan",Lore:["Powerful Chakra ball!"]},SkullOwner:{Id:"7dd5a6d3-3cfe-422a-9e1f-be554fa558ed",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvOWFjNTI0MTliOTkwMjU4MjhjODlmYTgyNTk0NWU2OTQ4ZTQ1YmI1YTIyZTQ0MjVhNTllOTA5NmU0YzFhYzM4In19fQ=="}]}}}
```

How will the command be if I add sharpness 10 and knockback 10 to this item?

Answer (score -1):

`/replaceitem entity @p slot.weapon.offhand minecraft:skull 1 3 {display:{Name:"Rasengan",Lore:["Powerful Chakra ball!"]},SkullOwner:{Id:"7dd5a6d3-3cfe-422a-9e1f-be554fa558ed",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvOWFjNTI0MTliOTkwMjU4MjhjODlmYTgyNTk0NWU2OTQ4ZTQ1YmI1YTIyZTQ0MjVhNTllOTA5NmU0YzFhYzM4In19fQ=="}]},ench:[{id:16,lvl:10},{id:19,lvl:10}]}}}`

In ench:[...] each compoud has an id and a lvl key. Id is the id of the enchantment (16 for sharpness, 19 for knockback) and lvl is the amplifier (so `{id:16,lvl:10}` means sharpness 10)

Comment: Sry that command dont work

Comment: /replaceitem entity @p slot.weapon.offhand minecraft:skull 1 3 {display:{Name:"Rasengan",Lore:["Powerful Chakra ball!"]},SkullOwner:{Id:"7dd5a6d3-3cfe-422a-9e1f-be554fa558ed",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvOWFjNTI0MTliOTkwMjU4MjhjODlmYTgyNTk0NWU2OTQ4ZTQ1YmI1YTIyZTQ0MjVhNTllOTA5NmU0YzFhYzM4In19fQ=="}]}}}

Comment: How to add ench shaprness 10 and knocback on this item?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you have an "*==*" that only has a value on one side (the jumble of letters), if this helps...